# What is Word Injection in Context of Natural Language Processing and Whats are its Applications?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, cpu-word, corpus

Hello All Community Members,

After going through various articles and blogs, I came to understand that suppose, in a corpus (`C1`), let's assume there exists a word (`w`). Now that same word (`w`) also appears in another related corpus (`C2`). Similarly, there exists `n` number of words in corpus.

By **word injection**, what I understand is that :- the word (`w`) in Corpus (C1) is replaced by its modified version (`.w`) with the assignment of some special character like (`.`, `_` or `$`) in corpus (`C2.`).

**Note:** The modified version of word (`.w`) does not belong to the corpus C1 and C2. The word `.w` is the same word as `w` used in other context.

IS THIS THE CORRECT EXPLANATION for WORD INJECTION in NLP?

For example, the word `system` is replaced by `_system`.

I hope this is correct definition of word injection. Does there exist any way in python to achieve the above mentioned concept?

Any help is appreciated.